# Session cookie persitance in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, session, iis, session-cookies

This is probably a duplicate question, but since I can't find the answer in the questions from the past I am going to ask again.

In my ASP.NET application, when I authorize the user, I set the custom FormsAuthenticationTicket. The persistance variable is false, so the authentication cookie should only be valid for current session.

My question is when would this session end? I restart my IIS Express development server, I shut down the dev machine, etc, and the session seems to be still active and the user is authenticated with that cookie.

How come in my VS 2012 + IIS Express environment sessions are immortal?

Comment: Cookie "sessions" are browser sessions, not server sessions.

Comment: Andrew Barber is correct. To end your session close all instances of your browser. Or provide a log out button and click it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not an issue. You can restart the server and as long as the authentication cookie is still valid, the user is considered logged in. Remember, HTTP is a disconnected protocol.

The cookie will be removed the moment the user logs out and you programmatically remove the cookie or when the user closes his browser.